# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin

Tags: java, spring, exception

**StackTrace:**

> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
> **WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loryCat' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin**
> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loryCat' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
> at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
> at com.example.springcontext.Application.main(Application.java:7)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin
> at java.base/jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport.checkRange(RandomSupport.java:232)
> at java.base/java.util.random.RandomGenerator.nextInt(RandomGenerator.java:679)
> at com.example.springcontext.CatStrengthCalculatorBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CatStrengthCalculatorBeanPostProcessor.java:20)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
> ... 11 more

Process finished with exit code 1

**application-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean class="com.example.springcontext.CombatCat" id="loryCat">
        <property name="name" value="Lori"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.example.springcontext.CombatCat" id="baxterCat">
        <property name="name" value="Baxter"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.example.springcontext.FightClubImpl" id="fightClub">
        <property name="loryCat" ref="loryCat"/>
        <property name="baxterCat" ref="baxterCat"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.example.springcontext.CatStrengthCalculatorBeanPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

**Class CombatCat:**

```
package com.example.springcontext;

public class CombatCat {

    private String name;

    @CalculateCatStrangth(minStrength = 10, maxStrength = 14)
    private Integer strangth;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getStrangth() {
        return strangth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CombatCat{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", strangth=" + strangth +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show `CatStrengthCalculatorBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CatStrengthCalculatorBeanPostProcessor.java:20)` ;)

Comment: CatStrangth? is this just a typo perhaps?